# TabPageIndicator : Not able to refresh view of fragment having ListView after getting response from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, viewpagerindicator

I am using `TabPageIndicator` (Library [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)). I am having 2 tabs. Both are displaying 
same lab result differently. One tab groups the result by its date & other tab groups by teat name.

My aim is to make only one server call & use the generated POJO in both fragment of ViewPager.
I have created custom `FragmentPagerAdapter` in which I am initializing fragments in `getItem()` as follow:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                if(labsByDateFragment == null){                     
                    labsByDateFragment = new LabsByDateFragment();
                    fragment = labsByDateFragment;
                }
                break;
            case 1: 
                if(labsByTestFragment == null){                 
                    labsByTestFragment = new LabsByTestFragment();
                    fragment = labsByTestFragment; 
                }
                break;
        }

        return fragment;
    }
```

Both `LabsByDateFragment` & `LabsByTestFragment` extends `Fragment` and are having `ListView`. Now initially when my `FragmentActivity` launches, it will show both fragment blank and calling `AsyncTask` to make web service call for data.

Once the data is received from AsyncTask, I am calling `notifyDataSetChanged(labResponse)` in `OnCompleteListner` as follow:

```
 private OnCompleteListner onCompleteListner = new OnCompleteListner() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object obj) {

                LabsResponse labResponse = (LabsResponse) obj;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(labResponse);          

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) DialogFactory
                        .getDialogWithOkButton(
                                "Oops..Failed to get your Results...Sorry..",
                                ResultsLauncher.this);
                dialog.setOwnerActivity(ResultsLauncher.this);
                dialog.show();
            }
        };



    public void notifyDataSetChanged(LabsResponse labsResponse){

            labsByDateFragment.setLabsResponse(labsResponse);            
            labsByTestFragment.setLabsResponse(labsResponse);            

    }
```

setLabsResponse in both fragment just get the list of labs grouped accordingly (By Date or By Name) and Initialize my custom `ListView Adapter`. And bind the adapter with ListView.

My issue is that I am getting ListView Displayed in only 1st fragment.But the 2nd fragment remains blank. Also the ListView of 1st Frgament (with is LabsByDateFragment) shows data grouped by Lab's Test Name. But if I change the order of calling `setLabsResponse` in `notifyDataSetChanged` as follow, it will show me results grouped by date:

```
public void notifyDataSetChanged(LabsResponse labsResponse){             

        labsByTestFragment.setLabsResponse(labsResponse);            
        labsByDateFragment.setLabsResponse(labsResponse);            

}
```

So, It is showing data according to last grouped lab response.
Don't know where I am making mistake.

Comment: Anyone who has similar problems with `TabPageIndicator` ????